# Tensorflow-metal (intel Mac 2019 / AMD-GPU) errors during training

Tags: python-3.11, tensorflow-metal

Using MacOS in a python virtual environment with TensorFlow-Metal
while running training i got the below errors, using a 2019 Intel mac with AMD GPU.

What's the meaning and cause for this errors

**(venv-metal) XXX@XXX-MBP web3Test % python --version
Python 3.11.6**

Chipset Model: AMD Radeon Pro 5500M
Type: GPU
Bus: PCIe
PCIe Lane Width: x16
VRAM (Total): 8 GB
Vendor: AMD (0x1002)
Device ID:
Revision ID:

Epoch 1/10
2024-03-26 23:27:28.459378: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:114] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.

**2024-03-26 23:27:28.496988: F metal_plugin/src/graph/remapper/remapper.cc:3827] Mutation::Apply error: fanout 'AssignSubVariableOp_3' exist for missing node 'Pow_3'.**

Tried google search but not much info available relating to error.